# SQL query interpretation confirmation

Tags: sql, oracle

How many rows of data shall be returned?

To pass each fitness category, a mark of 100 is required.

```
SELECT Fitness_id, SUM(NVL(Marks,100))
FROM Fitness
GROUP BY Fitness_id
Having SUM(Marks)> 400
```

Assume there are 10 rows and each contains a Mark value  100 except for one, which has a null value in the mark field. First 5 Fitness Category 0 and last 5 is 1.

So SUM(NVL(Marks,100)) is equated to

```
(Imaginary)
Fitness_Category : Marks
     0           : 500
     1           : 500
```

But the Having condition for marks causes fitness_category not to be shown, am I right since NVL does not apply to the Having cause....so the Fitness_Category (1) is 400+NULL = 400 so only the (0) category meets the condition?

** Only 1 row of query is to be shown?

Comment: You explained it all: the SUM in the HAVING does NOT include the NULL row, so it's category does not pass the test.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and find out:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE fitness ( fitness_id, marks ) AS
SELECT 0,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 0,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT Fitness_id, SUM(NVL(Marks,100))
FROM   Fitness
GROUP BY Fitness_id
Having SUM(Marks)> 400
```

**Output**:

> ```
> FITNESS_ID | SUM(NVL(MARKS,100))
> ---------: | ------------------:
>          0 |                 500
> ```

You are correct that the `NULL` row will not contribute to the sum as the `NVL(Mark, 100)` applies only in the `SELECT` clause and not in the `HAVING` clause.

**Query 2**:

```sql
SELECT Fitness_id, SUM(NVL(Marks,100)) AS total_marks
FROM   Fitness
GROUP BY Fitness_id
Having SUM(NVL(Marks,100))> 400
```

or

**Query 3**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT Fitness_id,
         SUM(NVL(Marks,100)) AS total_marks
  FROM   Fitness
  GROUP BY Fitness_id
)
WHERE  total_marks > 400
```

**Output for Q2 & Q3**:

> ```
> FITNESS_ID | TOTAL_MARKS
> ---------: | ----------:
>          1 |         500
>          0 |         500
> ```

Both of these output rows for both `fitness_id`s as the `NVL(Mark,100)` is applied to the group's filter clause (i.e. `HAVING` is query 2 or on the outer-query for query 3).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a08c132f6275988fdc025a11cc1be061)*